# access reference attachment content using outlook REST API

Tags: outlook-restapi

I'm using outlook rest api to scan email and access all its attachments. For attachments which are copied this works ok. But if the attachment is uploaded to one drive and sent as link, then I did not find a way to access its content.

using the //attachments endpoint, I get the folloing data for this attachment:

```
 {'@odata.id': "....",
 '@odata.type': '#Microsoft.OutlookServices.ReferenceAttachment',
 'ContentType': 'text/plain',
 'Id': '....',
 'IsInline': True,
 'LastModifiedDateTime': '2017-12-14T13:07:47Z',
 'Name': 'ccc.txt',
 'Size': 418}
```

Is there anyway to access the attachment content in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The properties you need are only available on the `/beta` endpoint (I'm guessing you're using `/v2.0`?)

The `SourceUrl` property contains the URL to access the attachment.

```
GET /api/beta/me/messages/{message-id}/attachments

{
    "Id": "AAMkADBlNmQ2MTFl...",
    "LastModifiedDateTime": "2017-12-14T16:21:02Z",
    "Name": "Document1.docx",
    "ContentType": null,
    "Size": 13955,
    "IsInline": false,
    "SourceUrl": "https://1drv.ms/w/s!AuZOv...",
    "ProviderType": "OneDriveConsumer",
    "ThumbnailUrl": "",
    "PreviewUrl": "",
    "Permission": "Other",
    "IsFolder": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this

Comment: thanks. I can get the SourceUrl, is there an API I can use in order to access the content itself?

Comment: Probably the Graph would work, it can access OneDrive. You may be able to just do a GET on it with any HTTP API though since it's a sharing URL.